# PHP return the key of assoiative array by value without using foreach

Tags: php

I need to make a function to pass any value of this array and return its key without using foreach. as example if `US` is passed,`5` will return.

```
$array = [
    5 => [
       0 => 'US',
       1 => 'AI'
    ],
    20 => [
       0 => 'GB',
       1 => 'GG',
       2 => 'IM',
       3 => 'JE'
    ],
    23 => [
       0 => 'DK'
    ]
];
```

Comment: Not clear why you can't use `foreach`? Also what if `US` is duplicated in key `23` for example - what should be returned then?

Comment: No duplications as those values are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Filter your array to get subarrays where 'US' exists
$filterd = array_filter($array, function($v) { return in_array('US', $v); });
// Take the first key from filtered result:
print_r(array_keys($filterd)[0]);
```

Demo is [here](https://3v4l.org/NUgRH).